# How to achieve such grid effect with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, grid, jquery-masonry

does anyone has any idea how to achieve that effect?

[image]

I've tried with several plugins (Masonry, Packery) but with no luck. Has anyone encoutered that kind of grid before?

Comment: Check out Isotope
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html

Comment: I would second @DannyGibas advice for using jQuery Isotope, which is made by the same guy who made Masonry. But is a more full featured grid plugin: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html